# Slack Events API sending empty token and challenge when verifying function URL to enable event subscription

Tags: amazon-web-services, slack, slack-api

So I'm trying to build a slack app and enable event subscription. But to do this I need to verify the URL of my function by returning the value of challenge. I've

- Set up a simple Lambda function in AWS and hooked up to API Gateway
- Confirmed the API Gateway URL works by navigating to it in browser
- Given the URL when enabling event subscription in slack app builder web app.

I expect the request sent to the URL by slack to contain a value for "token" and "challenge" in the request body, but they're just blank.

How can I get the test request slack sends to actually populate the values? The [docs](https://api.slack.com/apis/connections/events-api#the-events-api__subscribing-to-event-types__events-api-request-urls__request-url-configuration--verification) suggest that these values should just be pre-populated by default, but they aren't in my case. (see picture)

Any suggestions appreciated thanks.

*url_verification event body sent by slack*
[image: screenshot showing url_verification event body sent by slack]

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to add to the Lambda a return challenge at the top of the Lambda so then whenever the challenge is sent by Slack your Lambda will always answer back?

```py
def lambda_handler(data, context):
    if data['type'] == 'event_callback':
        if "challenge" in data:  # auth event
            return data["challenge"]

    # continue with your process below
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use Socket Mode and bypass responding to the challenge entirely. https://api.slack.com/apis/connections/socket

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when my end-point needed authorization that I hadn't granted Slack. Verification worked when [AllowAnonymous] was put before the end-point controller method